# Team->Commit in Eclipse shows resources from a symlinked directory. How to ignore?

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I want to commit my project into svn, Eclipse displays a list of files in our tmp directory. Eclipse offers the possibility to add all these files to svn. But I don't want that, I want Eclipse to ignore the entire directory.

**About the project**

Our project contains a symlink 'tmp' where all our cache files are written to:

> lrwxrwxrwx  1 tijmen tijmen    11 Oct 14 11:28 tmp -> ../tmp

The **tmp** symlink is **already** added to svn:ignore. The **../tmp** directory is not in version control.

The **../tmp** directory contains a lot of cache files (837 as of now). Every time I do Team->Commit it lists all the cache files as New in the Content column. Because the list is so long it is very hard to find the files I actually want to add and/or commit.

Is there a setting in Eclipse which enables me to ignore contents of a (symlinked) directory in the Team->Commit view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution.

Right mouse on project -> Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters. Here I created an exclude filter to exclude symbolic links. Luckily I have only one symbolic link in this project. For other projects a stricter filter can be created.

Comment: very useful question and answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Add the selected tmp symlink to the svn:ignore property of its container folder. If it has not been added to the repository at all, simply right click on the folder, and select Team/Add to SVN Ignore (or something really similar name).

Otherwise you might have manually remove the existing folder, and add the corresponding property to its container folder.

**EDIT:** BTW. I am using the Eclipse Subversive plug-in; if you are using the Subclipse plug-in, search for option setting the svn:ignore properties.

Comment: It's already added to svn:ignore, which I stated in my question. I think svn itself ignores the symlink correctly, but eclipse follows the symlink and sees something new becuase ../tmp is not in ignore. I also use Subversive.